# Converting ANSI to UTF-8 & java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, utf-8, heap-memory, ansi

My final goal is to convert a file from ANSI to UTF-8. To do so, I use some code with Java :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class ConvertFromAnsiToUtf8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {
            Path p = Paths.get("C:\\shared_to_vm\\test_encode\\test.csv");
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(Files.readAllBytes(p));
            CharBuffer cb = Charset.forName("windows-1252").decode(bb);
            bb = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(cb);
            Files.write(p, bb.array());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } 

    } 

}
```

The code works perfectly when I test it on small files. My file is convert from ANSI to UTF-8 and all characters are recognize and well encoded. But as soon as I try to use it on the file I need to convert, I get the error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

So far as my understanding goes, I got like 1.5 million lines in my file so I am pretty sure I create too many objects with my application.

Of course, I have checked what this error means and how I could solve it (like [here](https://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2011/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space.html) or [here](https://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2011/05/java-heap-space-memory-size-jvm.html) for example) but is improving the memory capacity of my JVM the only way to solve it ? And if it is, how much more should i use ?

Any kind of help (tip, advice, link or else) would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Don't read the whole file at once:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(Files.readAllBytes(p));
```

Instead, try to read line-by-line:

```
Files.lines(p, Charset.forName("windows-1252")).forEach(line -> {
   // Convert your line, write to file
});
```

Comment: This fails to close the input stream. You have to call `Stream.close()` on the result of `Files.lines()`. This approach is "lossy" in that it can alter line endings.

Answer (score 1):

Stream the input, convert the character encoding, and write the output as you go. This way, you don't need to read the entire file into memory, but only as much as you want.

If you want to minimize the number of (slowish) system calls, you could use a similar approach, but explicitly create a `BufferedInputStream` with a larger internal buffer, and then wrap that in an `InputStreamReader`. But the simple approach shown here is unlikely to be a critical point in many applications.

```
private static final Charset WINDOWS1252 = Charset.forName("windows-1252");

private static final int DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE = 8192;

public static void transcode(Path input, Path output) throws IOException {
    try (Reader r = Files.newBufferedReader(input, WINDOWS1252);
         Writer w = Files.newBufferedWriter(output, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW)) {
        char[] buf = new char[DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE];
        while (true) {
            int n = r.read(buf);
            if (n < 0) break;
            w.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, erickson. Your input really helped me get the grasp on my problem. The only thing I didn't entirely get is where to write the path for my input and my output. I tried to do that :

Path input = Paths.get("/myInputPath/myAnsiFile.csv");
Path output = Paths.get("/myOutputPath/myUtf8File.csv");
    
but it didn't work. Sorry if my question sounds noobish. I am still new to Java...

Comment: @DavidJoshua Perhaps it was because the file that you tried to write to already existed. For safety, I included an option (`StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW`) that will prevent the new file from overwriting an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large file, which is larger then available random access memory you should convert characters chunk-by-chunk.

Following you can found the example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class Iconv {

    private static void iconv(Charset toCode, Charset fromCode, Path src, Path dst) throws IOException {
        CharsetDecoder decoder = fromCode.newDecoder();
        CharsetEncoder encoder = toCode.newEncoder();
        try (ReadableByteChannel source = FileChannel.open(src, StandardOpenOption.READ);
                WritableByteChannel destination = FileChannel.open(dst, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING,
                        StandardOpenOption.WRITE);) {
            ByteBuffer readBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
            while (source.read(readBytes) > 0) {
                readBytes.flip();
                destination.write(encoder.encode(decoder.decode(readBytes)));
                readBytes.clear();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        iconv(Charset.forName("UTF-8"), Charset.forName("Windows-1252"), Paths.get("test.csv") , Paths.get("test-utf8.csv") );
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Victor. I tried your solution since it looked easier to me and it seemed to have worked perfectly ! You really helped me here !